# Use the Windows 7 RSS gadget without IE

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, rss, desktop-gadget

Is it possible? I have uninstalled IE, it was the first thing I did but if I understand this gadget correctly you're supposed to add entries to it by first adding them to IE, which I don't have and don't want to have. How can I use it without using IE?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, you are talking about RSS feed url. 1st go to the site you want to get RSS feed in firefox. Then choose live bookmark button of firefox. Firefox will preview the feed, copy URL from address bar from firefox. Add the feed URL to the gadget.

Please feel free to delete if I am wrong.